# Choose Visual Studio version

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I want to install newer Visual Studio Express IDE. The question is whether VS 2017 is best or it has problems which do not exist in VS 2015. I prefer to install latest possible version to avoid upgrade in the next 1-2+ years. On the other hand if it runs slowly and new features are not important for me, I can get older version. Currently VS 2013 is the newest version that I have (and use 2010 most time). It is another question but is there any license limitations of express edition (2015/2017) for compilation of commercial software?

Comment: The NuGet Package Manager is heavenly improved since VS 2013. I cannot answer the point regarding commercial software. Xamarin aspects / templates are better integrated in comparison to VS 15. Why should it perform slowly? An intro can be seen :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/whats-new-in-visual-studio

Comment: @mnemonic I guess about speed because VS2010 was much slower than VS2008.

Comment: "Slowly" means you should upgrade your hardware. Seriously, nowadays  who cares upgrading frequently? Microsoft ships new Visual Studio releases quite often now, if it surprises you, https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-release-rhythm

Comment: @LexLi "Slowly" means 3-5+ times slower. If you have migrated from 2008 to 2010, you will understand what means slowly. Even 2012/2013 are faster than 2010. And there was surprise like VS 2010 Pro does not support Win Mobile projects but VS 2008 Pro supported Win Mobile. For such reasons I'd like to know what to expect from newer versions because downgrade is not fun. Some bad surprises are not visible from day 1.

Comment: I started from Visual Studio 2003, so I know what happened in the past. But except that you are working on the "legacy" technologies, there is no good reason to stay on old VS releases. The disaster of Visual Studio 2010 has its historical reasons (first release to fully migrate to WPF and .NET 4), and it took two years for Microsoft to respond. Consider how fast VS2017 updates, such is less likely to happen.

Comment: I installed VS2017. The bad surprise was the need of 35GB SSD space. The IDE seems run fast. Not sure how soon will be available the next release and whether it will add something significant.